# Hashtable Subclass With Overloaded Operators

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Taking the example Hashtable subclass created in c#:

```cs
public class CustomHashtable : Hashtable
{
    public CustomHashtable() : base() { }
    
    public CustomHashtable(Hashtable a) : base(a) {}

    public string GetFoo()
    {
        return "bar";
    }

    public static CustomHashtable operator +(CustomHashtable a, Hashtable b)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in b)
        {
            a.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value + "z");
        }

        return a;
    }
}
```

While running this as a csharp console application you get the appropriate typed overload:

```cs
var ch = new CustomHashtable(new Hashtable(){
    { "Age", 54 }
});

ch += new Hashtable(){
    { "LastName", "Jobs" },
    { "FirstName",  "Steve"}
};

System.Console.WriteLine(ch.GetType()); // CustomHashtable
System.Console.WriteLine(ch.GetFoo()); // bar
```

However, when importing this in PowerShell I get an error stating the method doesn't exist for `System.Collections.Hashtable`:

```
Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot/CustomHashtable.dll"

$Hash = [CustomHashtable]::New(@{
    Foo = 'Bar';
})

$Hash += @{
    Name = 'Toot';
}

$Hash.GetFoo()

Line |
  18 |  $Hash.GetFoo()
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.Hashtable] does not contain a method named 'GetFoo'
```

This works however if you explicitly cast to type of:

```
Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot/CustomHashtable.dll"

$Hash = [CustomHashtable]::New(@{
    Foo = 'Bar';
})

[CustomHashtable]$Hash += @{
    Name = 'Toot';
}

$Hash.GetFoo() //bar
```

Which for many reasons isn't ideal.

Is there anyway for PowerShell to pick up this typed overload?

Comment: I'll need to do a bit of digging, but I honestly don't think this is doable. PowerShell's runtime binders has special hardcoded logic for the binary operation `$AnIDictionary + $AnotherIDictionary` that causes PowerShell to copy entries from both  operands to a new Hashtable and outputs that. In other words, applying `+` to two `IDictionary` instances will _always_ result in a (built-in) hashtable

Comment: Good call out @MathiasR.Jessen I believe you are right. I haven't gotten this far since the method was failing, but just printing out the results in PowerShell, the overloaded method appears to not be called at all as I am not seeing values suffixed with `z`

Comment: Found the relevant code, I've posted a more comprehensive explanation below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyway for PowerShell to pick up this typed overload?

### Nope, at least not for dictionary types.

**TL;DR**: PowerShell's binary operation binder (the runtime component that figures out how to evaluate binary operator expressions, including `@{} + @{}`), has some hardcoded logic specifically for adding two objects together that both implement the `IDictionary` interface - and it'll never return your custom dictionary type.

**Let's dive into the source code and find out what that looks like!**

PowerShell's parser is going to turn the expression `@{} + @{}` into a [`BinaryExpressionAst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.binaryexpressionast?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) object. PowerShell's internal compiler then in turn has to resolve the appropriate operator implementation for the given operands, and construct an expression tree that can actually be evaluated at runtime.

If we look specifically at the code path evaluating binary expressions, we'll find that the compiler [defers the operation to the `PSBinaryOperationBinder`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/fa3aa1647527c032a6faa54b35b44f70b16d7dae/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/Compiler.cs#L5734-L5741) class:

```
public object VisitBinaryExpression(...)
{
    // ...

    switch (binaryExpressionAst.Operator)
    {
        // ...
        case TokenKind.Plus:
            if (lhs.Type == typeof(double) && rhs.Type == typeof(double))
            {
                return Expression.Add(lhs, rhs);
            }

            binder = PSBinaryOperationBinder.Get(ExpressionType.Add);
            return DynamicExpression.Dynamic(binder, typeof(object), lhs, rhs);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Alright, getting closer - now we know that the actual implementation for `+` applied to two hashtables is resolved somewhere in `PSBinaryOperationsBinder` and we'll want to look for code constrained by the expression type `Add`.

Digging into the source code once again, we'll find [this path in the binder](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/fa3aa1647527c032a6faa54b35b44f70b16d7dae/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/runtime/Binding/Binders.cs#L2732-L2745):

```
private DynamicMetaObject BinaryAdd(...) 
{
    // ...

    if (target.Value is IDictionary)
    {
        if (arg.Value is IDictionary)
        {
            return new DynamicMetaObject(
                Expression.Call(CachedReflectionInfo.HashtableOps_Add,
                                target.Expression.Cast(typeof(IDictionary)),
                                arg.Expression.Cast(typeof(IDictionary))),
                target.CombineRestrictions(arg));
        }

        return target.ThrowRuntimeError(new DynamicMetaObject[] { arg }, BindingRestrictions.Empty,
                                        "AddHashTableToNonHashTable", ParserStrings.AddHashTableToNonHashTable);
    }

    // ...
}
```

So obviously, something special happens when the `target` (the left-hand side operand) and the `arg` (the right-hand side operand) both implement the `IDictionary` interface - **as is the case here**!

The dynamic expression passed to `Expression.Call` as `CachedReflectionInfo.HashtableOps_Add` is a reference [to this method, `HashtableOps.Add(...)`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/runtime/Operations/MiscOps.cs#L1380-L1406), where the problem becomes apparent:

```
internal static object Add(IDictionary lvalDict, IDictionary rvalDict)
{
    IDictionary newDictionary;
    if (lvalDict is OrderedDictionary)
    {
        // If the left is ordered, assume they want orderedness preserved.
        newDictionary = new OrderedDictionary(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
    else
    {
        newDictionary = new Hashtable(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    // Add key and values from left hand side...
    foreach (object key in lvalDict.Keys)
    {
        newDictionary.Add(key, lvalDict[key]);
    }

    // and the right-hand side
    foreach (object key in rvalDict.Keys)
    {
        newDictionary.Add(key, rvalDict[key]);
    }

    return newDictionary;
}
```

As you can see, `newDictionary` is either an ordered dictionary (equivalent to `[ordered]@{}`) or a hashtable (`@{}`), hence the behavior you observe.

Comment: awesome answer!

Comment: agreed superb answer. I'll scan through github and see if there are any requests that similarly satisfy this, if not I'll create one. Thanks for the resource links as well! Much appreciated

Comment: @soulshined You're most welcome, and please do! :) FWIW, my personal preference for an alternative would be to define an `Append(Hashtable other)` method for ingesting an existing hashtable - but that obviously won't safeguard against accidental `+ @{}` :)

Comment: Teach me your ways! Great answer! O7